# Converting number string into number in an array

Tags: javascript, string

I have an array containing single strings. e.g. ["a", "b", "3", "c"];
However, I need any number in this array to be a number and not a string.

Result would be ["a", "b", 3, "c"]; so I could then run a regex and get all numbers out of the array.

Hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` and `isNaN`

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "3", "c"];
let final = a.map(val => !isNaN(val) ? +val : val)
console.log(final)
```

Comment: @Tony you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left (You get 2 reps as well)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `+` since `NaN` is evaluated as `false` if the value is not a number, so `(+e || e)` returns a number or the original value:

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "3", "c"];
const res = array.map(e=>(+e || e));

console.log(res);
```